# Google Charts + Google Sheets: Specified range does not identify data correctly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-visualization, jsapi

I settled on using Google Charts to draw the data from an auto-updating Google Sheet that draws from my Analytics account (the analytic API wasn't working out).

I've done quite a lot of reading, but I'm finding the query language reference to be a pain.

I've chosen to use the ChartWrapper.

https://jsfiddle.net/7xzv59kj/2/

```
     // Visits
      var wrap = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
      wrap.setChartType('ColumnChart');
           wrap.setDataSourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jICOBDvZzRxEThcWqnpFmNLUqjVP81Zd9RTwpbG29cE/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&range=Keywords-All_Time!B11:C12&headers=1&tq=');
      wrap.setContainerId('visits-all-time');
      wrap.draw();
  }
```

I want the chart to display the labels for Users and Sessions on the H-Axis, and then the values on the V-Axis. Instead, the data gets all jumbled and confused. I don't know what parameters to specify and how to label them properly.

***Spreadsheet located here.***

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jICOBDvZzRxEThcWqnpFmNLUqjVP81Zd9RTwpbG29cE

I would like to draw the data from the sheet titled `Keywords-All_Time` from `range B11:C12`

Comment: Check out https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example also upvoted ya :) @Joel

Comment: Can you give some of the column names (keys) you're going to be using? also what those values would be for an example. @Joel

Comment: Hi - I included the spreadsheet link and data range in the jsfiddle, but I'll post it here too:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jICOBDvZzRxEThcWqnpFmNLUqjVP81Zd9RTwpbG29cE

<<< Spreadsheet located here. Chart data on the sheet titled 'Keywords-All_Time' from range B11:C12

Comment: I will take a peak at the jsfiddle, but I would recommend you placing all information pertaining your question within the OP, otherwise you could get conflicting answers, or you wont get any answers and just a bunch of down-votes which defeats the purpose of why you're here ;)

Comment: OK, done. I think the answer is going to be something to do with my parameters not specifying the values/labels - the way I've specified the range seems to be working.

Before I used a setQuery command (select/limit/offset) and the data turned up with more formatting issues than the url method in the jsfiddle provided. It's annoying and strange.

Comment: Glad you where able to figure it out. I would recommend 'answering' your own question by giving what you had to do to resolve your issue so that it may help someone else out later down the road. :)

Comment: I didn't figure it out, I should make that clear - it was just conjecture

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was just my foggy brain - I took a break and came back to it yesterday to discover a couple issues:

```
  wrap.setDataSourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jICOBDvZzRxEThcWqnpFmNLUqjVP81Zd9RTwpbG29cE/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&range=Keywords-All_Time!B11:C12&headers=1&tq=');
```

1. My URL specifies the sheet twice. I recall someone telling me to format the range with the sheet, but I suppose I never erased the other parameter.
2. My table had the axes the wrong way around. I reversed them and found everything worked well from there.

I abandoned the chart wrapper and decided to move on to that when I actually have a need for it. Here's the current jsfiddle with the code I'm working on now: https://jsfiddle.net/c11c9a0w/19/

This will be extremely helpful for anyone having trouble building a dynamic dashboard from a Google Sheet that has multiple graphs on a single page, so feel free to work off of this.

-Joel